# substringFromIndex in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am getting error for this substringFromIndex in Swift 3. Below is the code in Objective-C, when ever I am trying to convert in Swift 3, substringFromIndex showing error.

```
    NSString *checkhypenString = [securityNumberField.text substringFromIndex: [securityNumberField.text length] - 5];
    checkhypenString = [checkhypenString substringToIndex:1];
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the code you wrote in Swift? Please explain your problem better so that people may help you.

Comment: try `let text = securityNumberField.text!
var checkhypenString = text.substring(from: text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: text.characters.count - 5))
checkhypenString = checkhypenString.substring(to: text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))`

Comment: You are asking about swift 3 but including objective-C code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
 let s = securityNumberField.text! // your string.
    let start = s.startIndex
    let end = s.index(s.endIndex, offsetBy: -5)
    let substring = s[start..<end]
    print(substring)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var index1 = string1.index(securityNumberField.text.endIndex, offsetBy: -4)

var substring1 = string1.substring(from: index1)
```